# How to add categories' separation lines

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart with multiple categories:

```
        xAxis: {
            categories: cat,
            labels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
```

The var **cat** is a dynamically generated array of categories [cat1, cat2, cat3...].

How can I add vertical lines or bands to separate categories on the X-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSQ6K/):

[image]

```
var cats = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six',
            'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'];

var colors = [
   '#2f7ed8', 
   '#0d233a', 
   '#8bbc21', 
   '#910000', 
   '#1aadce', 
   '#492970',
   '#f28f43', 
   '#77a1e5', 
   '#c42525', 
   '#a6c96a'
];

var bands = [];

for (var i=0; i < cats.length; i++)
{
    bands.push({color: colors[i],
                from:i-0.5,
                to:i+1});
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: cats,
            plotBands: bands
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
            color: 'black'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To create vertical lines, just set your x axis gridline width to something greater than 0.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.gridLineWidth

Bands can much more easily be accomplished with the `alternateGridColor` property, as here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yPLVP/53/